# Imagen y texto responsivos con Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Estoy agregando un contenedor con una fila y dos columnas en mi sitio con Bootstrap 5 que contiene una imagen y a la derecha un texto. Necesito que ambas sean responsive pero no lo estoy logrando.
Deberia verse de la siguiente forma:
[image: contenedor con una fila y dos columnas]

Este es mi codigo:

```html
<body>
      <div class="container-fluid bg-dark" id="about">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img
              style="
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
              "
              class="img-responsive"
              class="ms-5"
              src="https://www.gohawaii.com/sites/default/files/styles/island_curated_content_large/public/content-images/04681_1.jpg?itok=N2Ibq0uu"
              alt="Honolulu"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
              Buenos Aires es la provincia y localidad más grande del estado de
              Argentina. En los Estados Unidos, Honolulu es la más sureña de
              entre las principales ciudades estadounidenses. Aunque el nombre
              de Honolulu se refiere al área urbana en la costa sureste de la
              isla de Oahu, la ciudad y el condado de Honolulu han formado una
              ciudad condado consolidada que cubre toda la isla (aproximadamente
              600 km² de superficie).
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Pero se ve de la siguiente forma (con un margen a la izquierda que no quiero)
[image: Se ve asi]
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estás estableciendo `class="ms-5"`: margin-start = 5.

Comment: Gracias! eso estaba mal. Pero lo pude solucionar cambiando el div como <div class="d-flex justify-content-center bg-dark mb-3">

Comment: En ese caso, ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar cambiando el div como
`<div class="d-flex justify-content-center bg-dark mb-3">`